# Querying on Event Sequences With or Without Date Constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, indexing, sequence

Say I have a database of people with 0:many temporal events.

```
PERSON TABLE:
ID      Person  
--      ------  
1       Patrick
2       Sandy

EVENT TABLE:
ID      Event
--      -----
1       blow bubbles
2       visit SpongeBob
3       eat at the Krusty Krab

PERSON EVENT TABLE:
Person_ID   Event_ID    Date
1           3           2017-05-05
1           3           2017-05-09
1           2           2017-05-10
2           1           2017-05-04
2           3           2017-05-15
```

I'm interested in how to do queries like these:

- Find all people who ever ate at the Krusty Krab within 3 days after
  visiting SpongeBob.
- Find all people who ever blew bubbles, then visited SpongeBob, then
  blew bubbles again in that specific order (other intervening events
  are OK).
- Find all people who ever blew bubbles, then visited SpongeBob, then
  blew bubbles again in that specific order (other intervening events
  are not OK).
- Find all people who ever ate at the Krusty Krab at least 5 times in a
  7 day period.

Is there a name for this type of query?  Are there generalizable SQL strategies for approaching queries like these?  I'm particularly interested in how to do queries like these quickly.  Are there any specialized databases or indexes that can help improve performance on queries like these?

Comment: Looks like homework or similar. Show us what you've tried -  add the expected result, and your different query attempts. Also tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: You have to say "Ravioli, ravioli, give me the querioli."  Also, provide what you've tried.

Comment: Agree with preceding comments, if he's looking for how to write these queries. **Disagree**, if he's trying to *understand* these types of queries--which is how this questions reads to me.

Comment: I don't need SQL code for the query examples, just answers to my questions.  I work with hospital data and we often are interested in finding patients who have particular sequences of procedures/diagnoses.  I know how to do these comparisons in code, but need a more time-efficient approach and honestly don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These queries aren't close enough in function to have a single common function-based name or strategy.  At least none that I can think of.

They might be close enough in usage to call them all "data mining" or "marketing" queries.   However I doubt either of these would be useful in googling for a general-purpose strategy, if that's why you asked.

If you're interested in letting less sql-savvy users create and run ad-hoc queries like this and whatever else they might come up with, you might look into giving them a denormalized view or even a cube with every dimension they can think of wanting to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are so, so many different ways to do stuff like this... since your comments were just looking for logic direction... I hope this helps and makes sense.

**Find all people who ever ate at the Krusty Krab within 3 days after visiting SpongeBob.**

You can achive this by selecting all visits to the Krusty Krab, then seeing if that person is `IN` a query which checks if they visited Spongebob 3 days earlier. Hint: `... WHERE PersonId IN (SELECT PersonId WHERE DATEDIFF(day, SpongebobVisit, KrustyKrabVisit) >= 3)`

**Find all people who ever blew bubbles, then visited SpongeBob, then blew bubbles again in that specific order (other intervening events are OK).**

You can create three subqueries tables... blowing bubbles, visiting spongebob, and blowing bubbles.  Then `JOIN` in a chain where each `JOIN`s on a date greater than the last event. It will only return rows where those events are in sequence because of the `INNER JOIN`.

**Find all people who ever blew bubbles, then visited SpongeBob, then blew bubbles again in that specific order (other intervening events are not OK).**

Sort the tables by person and date and look into `LEAD` AND `LAG` functions.

**Find all people who ever ate at the Krusty Krab at least 5 times in a 7 day period.**

Look here: [Sql Query to find A series of dates that occur within 5 minutes of each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459851/sql-query-to-find-a-series-of-dates-that-occur-within-5-minutes-of-each-other)

**Are there any specialized databases or indexes that can help improve performance on queries like these?**

A standard index on Ids should be sufficient for these types of queries.

Edit: I'm not promoting, but there is a user on here who wrote a book called "SQL Antipatterns" that really dives into the proper ways to solve interesting problems like this. He usually shows one way that people would normally do it, then the proper way.