# Summing rows only if they're within a week of each other

Tags: t-sql, sum, case, case-when

I've got a table with ProductID, date, and price. I'm trying to write code that would:

- identify the week in which each product had the highest sales
- ignoring productid, find weeks in which sales are maximised i.e.
  split all the dates into 7-day periods such that within each 7-day
  period sales are maximised. These 7-day periods weeks aren't allowed
  to overlap

I'm really new to SQL and I've struggled with this for a couple of days and looked around stack overflow. With the first task I thought I found the ideal code but it seemed to work for others but only returned the sales of a product on a given day rather than a sum of the week.

```
Select a.date, a.productid, sum(sales) from 
 (SELECT [Date Of Sale] as 'Date'
  ,[Product ID] as 'ProductID'
  , [Sales in GBP] as 'Sales'
 FROM [blah].[blah-blah])
) as a
  where a.date between dateadd(day, -6, a.date) and dateadd(day, 0, a.date)
  group by a.date, a.productid;
```

I've tried to trim to what is necessary, but there's no error message, it just returns date, productid, sales but for the date '2007-01-13' for example it just returns the sales of the product from that day rather than the total sales from '2007-01-06' to '2007-01-13'.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would really help.  As phrased, this question sounds like three questions, which is rather broad.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL are you using? MySQL version 4.0 and higher has the function WEEK(), which will split date into weeks from 0 to 53, representing the order of weeks throughout the year. Looking at your code, and what you are trying to do I think something like the following might work for you:

```
  SELECT WEEK([Date of Sale]) as date,
         [Product ID] as product_id, 
         sum([Sales in GBP]) as sales  
    FROM [blah].[blah-blah]
group by 1,2
```

This will give you 52 or 53 rows, one for every complete and part week of the year(unless you have no sales in a given week). I hope this answers your question? If not I can offer other solutions, but i'm saving myself the writing time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment
This particular task is hoping to identify weeks that can start on any day. So for example if Product 3 sold the most in a 7-day period starting on a Wednesday the code would pick that up, whereas your code restricts us to start on a Monday.
I'm using SQL Server Management Studio by the way
I'd love to hear more ideas if you have any. I'm currently trying to build a functiont that would return a 1 if i.) the product ID matches and ii.) the sale was within a week before and a 0 otherwise. Do you have any insight into how to do that?

Comment: It's the dynamic dates which are going to run you into trouble. I don't mind putting my hand up and saying this is a little beyond my ability, but this might give you at least part of the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459851/sql-query-to-find-a-series-of-dates-that-occur-within-5-minutes-of-each-other